# Sheaf structure on reducible affine variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How we define sheaf structure on reducible affine variety $ X $ i.e  $ O_{X}(U)$, where $ U $ is open ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find everything you need in Gathmann's [class notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/de/alggeom.php). I follow his conventions, e.g. $K$ is the ground field and $A(X)$ is the coordinate ring of the affine variety $X$.

$\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is the set of **regular functions** on the open set $U$.

A regular funtion on $U$ is a map $\varphi : U \mapsto K$ such that for every $a \in U$, there is an open neighborhood $U_a \subseteq U$ of $a$, and polynomial functions $f, g \in A(X)$ such that for all $x \in U_a$, $g(x) \neq 0$ and $\varphi(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

In other words, a regular function is a function that is locally rational.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1377890)

Comment: @Jan True, I fixed this.